# How to code data files from excel into Rstudio

Tags: r, excel, dataframe, input

I am trying to import data from excel into R (stats class), but we are not allowed to use the import function. We have to code it in. I got help last week from a graduate student, but I think because I got a new laptop over the weekend, the Rmd file cannot be used as my reference markdown anymore. Here is what I've tried inputting:

```
library(tidyverse)
data.frame(readxl::read_excel(path = "./data/thedataweprovide.xlsx", sheet = "Problem 1"))
```

> Error: `path` does not exist: ‘./data/thedataweprovide.xlsx’
>   > setwd("C:/Users/Jasmine Ferrell/Documents/BME_Statistical_Methods/Project_1")
>   Error in setwd("C:/Users/Jasmine Ferrell/Documents/BME_Statistical_Methods/Project_1") : 
>     cannot change working directory
>   > pone
>   Error: object 'pone' not found
>   > setwd("C:/Users/Jasmine Ferrell/Documents/BME_Statistical_Methods/Project_1")
>   Error in setwd("C:/Users/Jasmine Ferrell/Documents/BME_Statistical_Methods/Project_1") : 
>     cannot change working directory
>   > setwd("C:\Users\ferre\OneDrive\Documents\BME_Statistical_Methods\Project_1")
>   Error: '\U' used without hex digits in character string starting ""C:\U"
>   > setwd(C:/Users/ferre/OneDrive\Documents/BME_Statistical_Methods/Project_1)
>   Error: unexpected '/' in "setwd(C:/"

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your paths are the problem. You could first try to get the working directory you are currently in with the function `getwd()` this may help you to figure out how you could correct your paths. Do not use single Backslashes (`\`) in paths, only use foreward-slashes (`/`).

Comment: Do I need to input anything into the parentheses to get the working directory or do I just code in getwd() ?

Comment: nothing, see the documentation here: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/getwd.html

Answer (score 0):

As saae mentioned its a problem with path. Try these and should be able to get it working.

Type in your Rstudio

```
getwd()
```

This gives the current path which is currently set. If you are files are somewhere else, then you won't find it.

To change the path

go to your file location and copy the path. For example in windows, you go to the folder and click on properties, there you will see location. Copy the location and add it to the below code.

```
setwd("//abcdefg/somerandomguy/Profile/Desktop/My files/R_project")
```

Then you can run your code to read the files.